# How do I turn off Google Chrome's terminal window?

Tags: google-chrome, terminal

For a while now, Google Chrome has been displaying an extra terminal window when I start it up. It occasionally displays some information but mainly just sits there quietly:

[image: Google Chrome terminal window]

If I close it, it closes my Chrome windows with it. It doesn't hurt anything but it's annoying and I want it gone. How do I set up Chrome so it doesn't display this terminal anymore? Thanks! I'm using Windows 10, and I have nothing in my startup related to Chrome.

Comment: 1) Which OS do you use? 2) What's in your Startup Applications? Please click [edit] and add that info to your original question so we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked a few things and found out what I did. In my Chrome shortcut, I had the arguments `--enable-logging --v=1` added on:

[image]

I remember doing this now that I see it, though I don't remember exactly why. I removed the arguments and no more terminal window

Answer (score -1):

Google says that error has to do with a subsystem app called [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/), it helps in loading web drivers for your browser. If you have all your bookmarks/passwords/etc. saved to a Google account, I'd just uninstall and reinstall Chrome to see if that resolves.